# Is there any trick to getting a WEBVIEW in OS X to goto links when you click on them?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a very very simple webview, that loads a URL that never changes, however when clicking on links, they do not load.

Comment: Is it possible that the links are supposed to open in a new window? That could break them.

Comment: No trick. Tell us more about these links. Show us some sample HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using the policy delegate did the trick